# css :last-child not quite right

Tags: css

Trying to reset the last image's margin to zero, but the last-child is resetting them all.
Not using this one correctly...

http://jsfiddle.net/telagraphic/MAgpU/

should it be?

```
div#social:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `img` in your source is the last child of its parent, an `a` tag.  You can fix the problem by using this instead:

```
div#social a:last-child img{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

While you're at it, remove the `div` qualifier from all your ID selectors.  (`div#social` becomes `#social`).  It's usually redundant since there's only going to be one element with that ID on the page, and could reduce selector performance.

Comment: There are valid uses for `div#id` format, namely specificity. Look at [this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jm5CW/1/), where the `id` only is not enough to override the parent element specificity in test 1, but the `div#id` format does for test 2.

Comment: @ScottS: I agree with your point but still, I would generally regard having to resort to this as poor CSS architecture

Comment: @o.v.--I would agree with you and also "generally regard having to resort to this as poor CSS architecture." I just wanted to point out that it is not technically "redundant" as derekerdmann stated.

Comment: thanks derekman, im so blind! I use the div#social in my css to remind me what im working on.